# How to fix this error: set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am learning to code linked list. i am currently trying to delete the first element of the linked list. so i wrote the following code.
It is working fine for first element. but it is showing the error for second element.

```
void deleteFirst(Node* head){

    Node* temp = head;
    head->data = temp->next->data;
    head->next = temp->next->next;
    free(temp);}
```

given linked list:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

after first deletion it is showing me:

```
 3 4 5 6 7
```

after second deletion it is showing me:

```
a.out(78094,0x7fff92d38380) malloc: 
    *** error for object 0x7ffb39400370: pointer being freed was not allocated
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Why are you freeing `temp`? Are you intending to free `head`? Because that's what it's doing.

Comment: You set temp = head, then free temp ... doesn't that sequence mean that the memory (of head, now also temp) has been returned to the heap?  and thus no-longer allocated for use, and is now available for another alloc ... You probably should make up your mind - use the space of head, or allocate a new head and then copy the values.  I expected the 1st and last lines ... so maybe just remove the middle 2 lines, and change head to point to head->next;

Answer (score 2):

Your's temp and head both point to the same memory. When you free temp, you free head as well. Check your logic and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping on that one. now i understand how to proceed with it.